# Prolog and recursive rules

Tags: prolog

```
compress([X,Y|Xs], Q) :-  dif(X,Y), compress([Y|Xs], QR), append([X], QR, Q).
compress([X,X|Xs], Q) :- compress([X|Xs], Q).
compress([], []).
compress([X|[]], Q) :- compress([], QR) ,append([X], QR ,Q).
```

I have one more question to above piece of code:

Let's consider:

```
compress([1,2,2,3,4], Q).
```

And let `Q` be instanitated to `_G900`. 
The first step is unifying to the first  rule. So:
    `compress([1,2|[2,3,4]], _G900) :- dif(1,2), compress([2|[2,3,4], G_901), append([1], _G901, _G900).`

And the problem is when it comes to the last subgoal- `append([1], _G901, _G900).` Why? I cannot understand how is it to possible to `append` `[1]` to `_G901`. After all, `G_901` is ANY instance. So, I have a problem with understanding how does works recurrence in Prolog. My intuition based on other languages is: 
Before `append` will be 'executed' `_G901` should be known, especially should be a empty list- becasue of the third rule ( stop condition recurrence).

Even if my intuition is right  I will ask for deeply explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This rule is a little odd: `compress([X|[]], Q) :- compress([], QR) ,append([X], QR ,Q).`. Since `compress([], QR)` can only result in `QR = []` according to your rules, then this means you have `append([X], [], Q)` which simply means `Q = [X]`. Also, `[X|[]]` is synonymous with `[X]`. So the rule is really simply `compress([X], [X]).`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the context for your question regarding `_G901`. Are you doing a trace for a specific query? What query did you run? Another semantic point: `append([X], QR, Q)` is the same as `Q = [X|QR]`. You don't really need `append` here. In fact, it would be common to write this rule as: `compress([X,Y|Xs], [X|QR]) :-  dif(X,Y), compress([Y|Xs], QR).`

Comment: Altogether the use of `append/3` in this context is a bit questionable. Did you write this definition of `compress/2` yourself and you want to know why it works, or you found the definition somewhere and you want to know how it works? Or is it just a question about how `append/3` works?

Comment: I write it on my own. But, as I described in the first post, I don't understand  at all what I am doing :D

Comment: *My intuition based on other languages is: Before append will be 'executed' `_G901`should be known*. That's where Prolog is different. `_G901` does **not** need to be known before the `append` is called.  I often tell beginners when learning Prolog to forget just about everything the know about other languages because, frankly, it just gets in the way. It causes one to write bad Prolog. It's best to try to understand Prolog from elementary Prolog principles and go from there. Prolog has simple constructs, but can be very powerful.

Comment: To learn more about how predicates work in Prolog you should do the following. Run the Prolog interpreter (`swipl` on the command line, for example), and study the results of the following queries: `append(A, [a,b], L)`, `append(A, B, C)` , `member(a, L)`, and `length(L, N)`. You can also "play this game" with other predicates. These predicates are well-written *relations* and so give you a good answer whatever your input is. It seeks to find solutions to the query and will continue backtracking until the choices are exhausted (unless, of course, you *cut* (`!`) the backtrack).

Comment: @lurker, ok.
So, prolog differs *instantiated variable without value* and *instantiated variable with value*. I mean: Let X be a variable instantiated to _G100. And it (*instantiated variable without value*) can be unified in ANY moment to ANY term. But after unification we have a variable  _G100 which can be unified only to the same instance (*instantiated variable with value*) . Am I right?

Comment: *Instantiated* usually means the variable has been unified with a specific value or term and is *bound* (has no variables). If the variable has no value, it is *not instantiated* or *unbound*. It can, however, be *unified* with another variable. So you can say, for example, `X = Y, Y = 3, write(X), nl.` and you will get `3`.